# How do I draw shapes with custom coordinates in the Fyne GUI package

Tags: go, coordinates, drawing, fyne

I am using the Fyne GUI package for Go to draw lines and points for a project.

The documentation for the package describes how to draw several basic shapes, but does not explain how to use custom coordinates for these shapes.  Instead, the documentation describes default coordinates.  How do I draw custom lines with coordinates I control for these shapes?

Code described in the documentation:

```
myApp := app.New()
w := myApp.NewWindow("Line")

line := canvas.NewLine(color.White)
line.StrokeWidth = 5
w.SetContent(line)

w.Resize(fyne.NewSize(100, 100))
w.ShowAndRun()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you put your lines inside an unmanaged container (`container.NewWithoutLayout()`) it becomes your responsibility to place and size the contents.

https://developer.fyne.io/faq/layout

If you are looking to use a different coordinate system then you’ll need to add some maths to the mix.